# Función dentro de otra función en javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una web app para dar aprobación de las respuestas de un formulario a través de un correo electrónico.

Quisiera que además de eso, me enviara algunos correos que estarían condicionados a algunas de las respuestas del formulario.

Con animo de simplificar el código y darle un poco de orden, pensé en:

1. Hacerlo en el mismo proyecto, pero en un archivo de secuencia de
   comandos diferente.
2. En mi función principal (la que se dispara a través del correo electrónico) llamar la función que esta en el otro archivo de secuencia de comandos.

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

I

```
DLIBRO = "1JN41GTgAl8Vl8gqGbBcyfaMs......." 

IDHOJA = "Respuestas"

function doGet(e) {

  var numeroAutorizacion = e.parameter['IdAprob']

  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.openById(IDLIBRO).getSheetByName(IDHOJA)

  var aprobacion = hoja.getRange('I' + numeroAutorizacion).setValue("Si")

  var hoy = hoja.getRange('J' + numeroAutorizacion).setValue(new Date())

  correo()
}
```

Donde correo es la otra función.

Comment: Yo lo haría en el mismo proyecto pero en otro fichero gs, más que nada por coherencia. Una cosa es gestionar el formulario, otra cosa es enviar correos. Así no mezclas y es más fácil ordenar el código. Dado que todo el código tiene visibilidad en todos los ficheros no hay demasiado problema como en otros lenguajes, De cara a aprender google apps script en español tal vez te vaya bien un blog que estoy montando: http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/ Aún le falta mucho, pero me lo paso bien y aprendo escribiendo en el.

Answer (score 2):

En la primera versión del la pregunta se menciona que el código compartido no funcionó. Ello debe a que no se han separado las sentencias con punto y coma.

En relación a si es posible incluir en un mismo proyecto varios archivos y colocar en esto distintas funciones si es posible. El llamar una función que se encuentra en otro archivo en el mismo proyecto es muy sencillo. Ejemplo:

Código.gs

```
function principal() {
   //Llama la función llamada secundaria().
   secundaria(); 
}
```

Código 2.gs

```
function secundaria() {
   //Agrega al registro un mensaje de júbilo.
   Logger.log('Me llamaron. ¡Viva!'); 
}
```

Considerando el tipo de error, podría ser conveniente que revisaras un curso de JavaScript o bien la [guía de JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/.) publicadas Mozilla Developers Network (MDN), ya que Google Apps Script está basado en dicho lenguaje.

En cuanto a recursos sobre Google Apps Script en español te podría ser de utilidad el siguiente playlist del canal de Google Developers: [Introducción a Google Apps Script](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuC7OUdarKuYq7VsyKrVPbsRSUrx25YvR)

Answer (score 0):

podrias obtener algunos valores con la funcion correo(), mas o meno asi:

```
function correo(id,respuesta,correo){
// Y aqui tu codigo con el vas a recoger los valores y despues la ejecucion del codigo.
}
```